# Create DataFrame from Loop with Bloomberg function

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I have a list of company ticker's:

```
df = {'Ticker': ['AVON LN EQUITY', 'GFS LN EQUITY'], 'Value': [1., 2.]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I am using the BLPAPI wrapper, https://github.com/alex314159/blpapiwrapper

Using this i would like to get a DataFrame, of all the prices over on a monthly basis. For this i am using the BLP class and BDH function. Settings below (the longer version is in the link):

```
def bdh(self, strSecurity='SPX Index', strData='PX_LAST', startdate=datetime.date(2013, 1, 1), enddate=datetime.date(2016, 9, 6),
        adjustmentSplit=False, periodicity='MONTHLY', strOverrideField='', strOverrideValue=''):
```

for simplicity i created a mini function:

```
def bloom_func(x, func):
    bloomberg = BLP()
    return bloomberg.bdh(x, func, strOverrideField='BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE', strOverrideValue='1GY' )
    bloomberg.closeSession()
```

Using these i can get a DataFrame for one equity.

```
Price = bloom_func('VOD LN EQUITY', 'PX_LAST')
print (c)
```

which works.

However, when i try to run this in a across the 2 companies using:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.apply(lambda x: bloom_func(x)) for p in df['Ticker']])
```

i get ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 0), indices imply (2, 2).

Comment: IIUC you need `df1 = pd.concat([df['Ticker'].apply(bloom_func)])`

Answer (score 1):

Was simpler than I thought

```
for d in df['Ticker']:
    x[d] = bloom_func(d)
```